# how to export table/crosstab from r to excel while keeping the format as it is

Tags: r, export, crosstab

I need to export a high dimension frequency table generated by crosstab() (Package: descr) on 2 rows and 2 column variables from R to excel without changing the pattern/format.

The crosstab() function is running with combination of other packages. Got from this tutorial: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html

Note: The page obtained the `crosstab` function with: source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r"). Credit was given to the `ctab()` function in the "catspec" package. One would be expected to also obtain the associated `print.crosstab` function, because the result is given a class of "crosstab".

Specifically, I want the same out-put in excel as the high dimension table generated using crosstab()  is displayed on R console.

```
install.packages("descr")
library(descr)
ID <- seq(1:177)
Age <- sample(c("0-15", "16-29", "30-44", "45-64", "65+"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Country <- sample(c("England", "Wales", "Scotland", "N. Ireland"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Health <- sample(c("Poor", "Average", "Good"), 177, replace = TRUE)
Survey <- data.frame(Age, Sex, Country, Health)
head(Survey)
crosstab_1 <- crosstab(Survey, row.vars = c("Age", "Sex"), col.vars = c("Health", "Country"), 
     type = "f", addmargins = FALSE)
print(crosstab_1)
```

I need to export to excel the crosstab format as it is comes out in console through print(crosstab_1) function.

Comment: The codes are following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an error with that code:

```
Error in crosstab(Survey, row.vars = c("Age", "Sex"), col.vars = c("Health",  : 
  The 'indep' (independent variable) is missing. Please, consider using either CrossTable() or freq().
```

I'm not a user of that package so decided against figuring out what caused the error. So I decided to show what I would have done to achieve what I think is your purpose. The `table` function in base-R is like the "crosstabs" function in SPSS. It generates a contingency table, a matrix-like object:

```
with(Survey, table( interaction(Age, Sex), interaction(Health, Country) ) )
#-----

               Average.England Good.England Poor.England
  0-15.Female                0            0            2
  16-29.Female               1            3            4
  30-44.Female               2            3            0
  45-64.Female               1            1            0
  65+.Female                 2            0            4
  0-15.Male                  1            3            1
  16-29.Male                 0            2            1
  30-44.Male                 2            3            1
  45-64.Male                 2            2            0
  65+.Male                   3            3            1

               Average.N. Ireland Good.N. Ireland Poor.N. Ireland
  0-15.Female                   1               2               0
  16-29.Female                  1               0               1
  30-44.Female                  2               0               1
  45-64.Female                  1               1               2
```

> snipped the rest of the output since it will clearly not be amenable to easy processing with Excel (or in my case OpenOffice)

Now expand the viewing console and repeat:

```
options( width=300)
with(Survey, table( interaction(Age, Sex), interaction(Health, Country) ) )
```

Most of the data is not visible on hte right side of the display but that doesn't matter. Now select it with your cursor-mousing, copy-, then paste into a blank region of your spreadsheet. What should appear is a dialog that allows specifying that this is fixed format data and allows you to adjust the column separators easily. Fiddle with the columns and hit OK and you're done.

You could also have used `capture.output` or `sink` to send this output to a file.

Addendum: The output of the `print.crosstabs` function from the site listed below in the comments is:

```
print(crosstab_1)
#----------------------------
             Health  Average                              Good                              Poor                          
             Country England N. Ireland Scotland Wales England N. Ireland Scotland Wales England N. Ireland Scotland Wales
Age   Sex                                                                                                                 
0-15  Female               2          1        4     1       3          2        1     3       0          3        1     1
      Male                 1          0        1     0       0          2        1     1       1          1        1     3
16-29 Female               1          1        1     3       1          1        2     2       0          2        0     1
      Male                 4          0        2     1       1          5        0     1       2          2        2     0
30-44 Female               2          1        2     3       2          2        1     2       1          2        1     3
      Male                 1          2        3     1       1          3        3     3       2          0        3     1
45-64 Female               1          0        1     3       3          0        4     1       0          0        1     0
      Male                 2          0        1     3       1          2        2     0       3          2        0     0
65+   Female               1          1        3     0       1          1        1     3       3          6        1     0
      Male                 0          1        1     0       3          0        0     1       1          2        1     2
```

Since is is text, you could import it  into excel (after using copy-paste or the `sink` or `capture.output` functions) using the program's fixed width text import facilities. It's essentially the same format as R base `ftable` function would give you for a 3-way classification.

Comment: Thank you sir for your useful answer. The crosstab() function is running with combination of other packages. Got from this tutorial: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html. By the way, I was interested to export output from r to excel without copy-paste. Sink option is very helpful. Thanks...

Comment: If this answered the question then a checkmark would avoid having it remain in the "unanswered queue".

Comment: The page obtained the `crosstab` function with: `source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")`. Credit was given to the `ctab()` function in the catspec package. One would be expected to also obtain the associated `print.crosstab` function because the result is given a class of "crosstab". I would see this as a very insecure method of setting up an AWS instance since your really don't know what would be in that code that you are pulling in from the outside.

Comment: i don't see this as solutions hence unchecking the answer could help to get correct answers here.

Comment: @ayushvarshney Not sure what your point is. The error message persists in the current version of this package. It says among other things: `The 'indep' (independent variable) is missing.` If you instead follow the link that I offered in the comment above you can create a version of `crosstabs` that overlays the crosstabs method in the "descr" packages and its `print` method that will succeed in producing output to the console. It's unclear what you consider to be a "correct method". I added a note on R-to-Excel transfer methods, a topic which has many other answers on SO as well.

Comment: @ayushvarshney Added an edit to the question since you apparently didn't read all the comments and follow the links.